# TypeError at /oauth/complete/mediawiki/ when upgrading to social-auth-app-django 3.3.0

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I'm running:

- Python 3.7.3
- Django 3.1.14
- social-auth-app-django 3.1.0

When I try to upgrade social-auth-app-django to 3.3.0 or 3.4.0, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_django/views.py", line 33, in complete
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/actions.py", line 45, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 40, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 181, in auth_complete
    return self.do_auth(access_token, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 192, in do_auth
    return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_django/strategy.py", line 107, in authenticate
    return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 80, in authenticate
    return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 83, in pipeline
    out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 113, in run_pipeline
    result = func(*args, **out) or {}
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/social_core/pipeline/user.py", line 119, in user_details
    setattr(user, name, value)
  File "/data/project/spi-tools-dev/www/python/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 547, in __set__
    % self._get_set_deprecation_msg_params(),

Exception Type: TypeError at /oauth/complete/mediawiki/
Exception Value: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.
```

when I try to authenticate.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like this is similar to https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/256

Answer (score 0):

The TL;DR is to add

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS = ['groups']
```

to settings.py.  See [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/256#issuecomment-1039417373) for the longer version.